# The number of solutions of $z^5+2z^3-z^2+z=a$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

How we can calculate the number of solutions of $$z^5+2z^3-z^2+z=a\;\;,\;\;a\in \mathbb{R}$$
in the half-plane $\mathfrak {Re}(z)\ge 0$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Complex solutions? Do you know the fundamental theorem of algebra? Are you counting with multiplicity?

Comment: If real solutions, I think your best bet is taking the derivative.  An odd-order polynomial like this will have at least one real solution, but between any two real solutions there will be an extremum -- which is to say a root of the derivative.  Since the $a$ in this doesn't affect the derivative, the result you get using it will be particularly helpful.

Comment: ...and edited out from under me.  You might get some help from the fact that a polynomial in real coefficients will always have its roots symmetrical about the real line: if $z$ is a root, then so is $z^*$.

Comment: I have added comments to @Micah's answer that (I believe) free it from requiring Wolfram Alpha. Take a look and see if you agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the locations of the roots in $\Bbb{C}$ will vary continuously with $a$, it suffices to figure out the values of $a$ at which they cross the imaginary axis and check some specific values in between. It will be helpful to notice that there is always exactly one real root, since $f'(x)=5x^4+5x^2+(x−1)^2>0$. The lone real root has the same sign as $a$.

Suppose the equation has roots of the form $ki$, for $k \in \Bbb{R}$. Then $k^5i-2k^3i+k^2+ki=a$; equating real and imaginary parts gives
$$
k^2=a \\
k^5-2k^3+k=0
$$
The second equation factors as $k(k^2-1)^2=0$; so we must have $k=0$ or $k=\pm 1$, and the critical values of $a$ are $a=0$ and $a=1$.

Now, notice:

- When $a=0$, the four complex roots must sum to zero by the Vieta formulae. The above calculation shows that none of the complex roots can be pure imaginary; since they come in conjugate pairs, it follows that two must have positive real part and the other two negative real part. So there are three total roots with non-negative real part.
- Slightly moving $a$ away from $0$ will not affect which half-plane those two conjugate pairs of roots are in. Since it will affect the sign of the real root, the equation has two roots with non-negative real part for $a=-\epsilon$ sufficiently small (and hence for all negative $a$) and three such roots for $a=\epsilon$ (and hence for all $a \in (0,1)$).
- When $a=1$, the quintic factors as $(z^2+1)(z^3+z−1)$. The $z^3+z-1$ factor includes the real root of the original equation, which must be positive as $a$ is; since its roots again sum to zero, its two complex roots will have negative real part. So there are three roots with nonnegative real part (the positive real root and $\pm i$).
- Finally, for very large $a$, roots all need to have large magnitude. And for large input, the mapping $z\mapsto z^5+2z^3−z^2+z$ is dominated by the $z^5$ term. Under the simpler mapping $z\mapsto z^5$, positive reals have a preimage located properly in each of the four quadrants (plus one real preimage). So for very large $a$, we reason there will be a root in each of the two right quadrants, and a root in each of the two left quadrants. This gives us three roots with nonnegative real part in total (counting the real one).

Putting all this together, the equation has two solutions with nonnegative real part when $a$ is negative, and three otherwise.

Comment: Micha - see my answer - Only need to use WA once to find the roots of $P'(z)$.

Comment: Since all five roots sum to $0$, when $a=0$ it is clear that one conjugate pair is in the left half-plane, and the other is in the right. Slightly moving $a$ away from $0$ will not affect which half-plane these pairs are in, but will move the real root in the same direction $a$ is moved. This covers your cases with $a\in(-\infty,1)$.

Comment: For $a=1$, there is the clear positive real root, and the quintic factors as $(z^2+1)(z^3+z-1)$. There are two purely imaginary roots. Again since all five roots sum to $0$, the other pair of conjugate roots must have negative real part. Now the cases $a\in(-\infty,1]$ are covered.

Comment: Finally for _very_ large $a$, roots all need to have large magnitude. And for large input, the mapping $z\mapsto z^5+2z^3-z^2+z$ is dominated by the $z^5$ term. Under the simpler mapping $z\mapsto z^5$, positive reals have a preimage located properly in each of the four quadrants (plus one real preimage). So for _very_ large $a$, we reason there will be a root in each of the two right quadrants, and a root in each of the two left quadrants. This covers all of your cases now without using WA.

Comment: One more note, since it is not explicit here. There is always exactly one real root, since $f'(x)=5x^4+5x^2+(x-1)^2>0$. The lone real root has the same sign as $a$.

Comment: @alex.jordan: Fantastic, thanks! I've incorporated your comments.